Nextjs router cache weird result
I am studying Nextjs router cache and I have a question about it. I have two Server Components , named SC1 , SC2 , If both components are rendered in build time (SSG) , I could get router cache as expected :

Server Builds SC1 , SC2 and saves the contents of the RSC format into Full Router Cache.
When a user first visits SC1 , server checks that theres is a Full Router Cache and responses. When client receives the reponse (that says response_A) , it saves it into Router Cache.
When a user navigates to SC2 , server also checks that theres is a Full Router Cache and responses. When client receives the reponse (that says response_B) , it saves it into Router Cache.
When a user navigates from SC2 to SC1 , nextjs checks that there is a Router Cache in the client and does not request the server to get the datas.

But when both SC1 , SC2 components are rendered in run time , I got some weird results :

Server Builds SC1 , SC2 and saves the contents of the RSC format into Full Router Cache.

When a user first visits SC1 , server checks that theres is a Full Router Cache and responses. When client receives the reponse (that says response_A) , it saves it into Router Cache.

When a user navigates to SC2 , server also checks that theres is a Full Router Cache and responses. When client receives the reponse (that says response_B) , it saves it into Router Cache.

When a user navigates from SC2 to SC1 , nextjs did not check if Router Cache exists and request the server to fetch again to get new datas.
Despite the weird situation , It will get router cache from step 4 when the user navigates from SC2 to SC1 again , but I still can't understand why it still fetched new datas first.
Could anyone explain the problem ? thank you !


I expect that router cache works the same no matter server components are rendered in run time or in build time.
